# Styling Forms with HAML in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, styling

So I'm making this website with rails using HAML that's similar to Dribbble, but I just named everything to a recipe website. I want to style these forms with bootstrap but I don't know how to style them with haml. All I want to do is make the text on the top and the input section below the text, and have some decent padding and make the boxes round.

Here is the section I want to style:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :image
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :link
  = f.input :description
  = f.input :notes
  = f.input :price
  = f.button :submit
```

Comment: @sawa I don't know how to select the description and the notes box and make the corners rounded.

Answer (score 0):

To add bootstrap to simple forms run

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

[more](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#bootstrap)

Comment: They are asking how to style the form, not how to install bootstrap.

Comment: This generator does not install bootstrap. it generates a configuration file, that formats the form the way  bootstrap expects [example](http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/examples/vertical)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Does it do that immediately without having to code?

Comment: Yes and by default it uses vertical form style. [Other options](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/master/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb) and [this](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/tree/master/app/views/examples) is how to use them.